# ¿Porque la entidad _ah_SESSION pesa tanto y no se libera el espacio?

Tags: google-datastore, google-app-engine, objectify

Estoy trabajando con **Google App Engine** y **Google Datastore** y la librería **Objectify** y todo va bien, pero he notado que la entidad `_ah_SESSION` esta incrementando demasiado y ocupa mas del 90% del tamaño total de mis entidades aun cuando por ahora solo soy yo quien esta probando la aplicación.

¿Existe alguna forma para poder evitar esto automaticamente?

Por ahora lo que hago es eliminar las entidades manualmente ya que es la información de las sesiones de los usuarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Las sesiones en App Engine no se borran al expirar, por eso continúan tomando espacio.

En Java hay un [servlet](http://www.radomirml.com/blog/2011/03/26/cleaning-up-expired-sessions-from-app-engine-datastore/) para limpiar las sesiones expiradas, pero tienes que configurar un [cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) para hacer la limpieza.

En python no hay un servicio dentro del API de forma nativa, pero esta el proyecto [gae-sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions), tiene varios años que no se mueve, pero te puedes basar en el método [delete_expired_sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/gaesessions/__init__.py)

Comment: Googleando lei que debo tratar esa entidad como las demas y que necesito crear algun tipo de mecanismo manual que revise las fechas y elimine las entidades viejas aunque no se si sea la mejor practica